# iPhone screensaver

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to get a real screensaver on iPhone?

I realize this drains the battery fast, but that actually is no concern to me.

Here's what I mean: after X minutes of no touch input, a pretty screensaver comes on and just goes until I touch the screen, at which point it instantly returns to where I was.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this on any iOS device unless you jailbreak it.

If you do choose to jailbreak, then you can install various apps from Cydia such as ScreenSaver which will do what you want.